# Live-streaming via camera for firebase with flutter/dart

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

Is it possible to add live-streaming via flutter/dart? Is the camera on dartpub good enough?
I want the livestream to be able to connect to firebase.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?